# Thread.sleep interrupts the code

Tags: java, interrupt

I am doing a Minesweeper program and this is my code for the ActionEvent where a button consisting a mine is clicked.

```
button.setIcon(mine);
/* try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
*/      
MSFrame.setVisible(false);
MSFrame.dispose();
Minesweeper.initialize(rows1, columns1, chance1);
```

the sleep is inside comments because otherwise the code doesn't work.

This code should:

- set the icon of the button to "mine icon"
- wait a second
- remove the JFrame
- initialize a new game

Currently when I have removed the sleep function it does Remove the JFrame and initialize a new game but it doesn't give me the mine icon. That's why I need the program to wait a while (to have time to show it) but if I put sleep in there, the code doesn't do anything. I've also tried Wait() function with no results.

I am pretty much a beginner and don't know yet what Threads really are. I just copypasted that sleep code. This is my first program and I'd like to finish it (the Minesweeper is otherwise finished).

Comment: what do you mean does nothing? doesn't it remove the JFrame and initialize a new game?